# process of iteration in nextflow

Tags: bash, shell, awk, bioinformatics, nextflow

I am trying to create a process in nextflow where it takes 2 inputs, the `krakenfile` which will be used directly, and the `fungalname` which contain multiple lines, every line contain a name of a specie.

I want to do an iteration inside the `fungalname` file, take it line by line, and for every line/specie I will look for all lines in the `krakenfile` that contain that name in their 3rd column.

For example If my `fungalname` contain this:

```
Aspergillus fumigatus
Candida albicans
```

And the `krakenfile` contain

```
xxxx  548   Aspergillus fumigatus 
zzzz  566   Candida albicans 
aaaa  598   Aspergillus fumigatus
kkk   888   Candida albicans
```

My outputs should be 2 files,`ASpergillus_fumigatus_lines.txt` and `Candida_albicans_lines.txt`, every one of them contain 2 lines (as the example above)

The problem is that my outputs files always are empty, though I am sure of the format, the localisation of my input files, I think it's a matter of process, can Anyone please help m, this is my code :

```
   params.fungaalnames="/home/aziz/pipeline/results/extraction/fungal_species.txt"
    params.krakeenfile="/home/aziz/pipeline/results/classification_before_filtration/output.kraken"

    

fungalnames = file(params.fungaalnames)
krakenfile = file(params.krakeenfile)


process fungal_reads_extraction {
     
     input:

     file fungalnames
     file krakenfile

     output:
     path "*" , emit: reads_extracted_out
     
     script:
     """
while IFS= read -r species_name; do
  awk -F'\t' '\$3 ~ "'\$species_name'" {print}' $krakenfile > "\${species_name}_lines.txt"
done < $fungalnames
     """

}


workflow {

fungalnames_ch=Channel.fromPath(params.fungaalnames)
krakenfile_ch=Channel.fromPath(params.krakeenfile)


fungal_reads_extraction(fungalnames_ch, krakenfile_ch) | view
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Focusing solely on the `awk` script; I will leave it to the OP to (re)format as needed for inclusion in the `nextflow` script file ...

---

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
BEGIN        { FS="\t" }
FNR==NR      { sp = $0                            # 1st file: copy specie
               gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"_",sp)         # replace spaces with "_"
               specie[$0]                         # save specie name as index to specie[] array
               fname[$0] = sp "_lines.txt"        # create filename associated with this specie
               next
             }
$3 in specie {                                    # 2nd file: if 3rd column is index in specie[] array then ...
               print $0 > fname[$3]               # print current line to associated file
             # close(fname[$3])                   # uncomment if awk complains of too many open file descriptors
             }
' fungalname krakenfile
```

**NOTES:**

- this replaces OP's current `while/read/awk` loop
- if the number of unique species is 'too large' then some versions of `awk` may complain of too many open file descriptors; uncommenting the `close(fname[$3])` command should alleviate this issue with the side effect that the script will run slower

This generates:

```
$ head *_lines.txt
==> Aspergillus_fumigatus_lines.txt <==
xxxx    548     Aspergillus fumigatus
aaaa    598     Aspergillus fumigatus

==> Candida_albicans_lines.txt <==
zzzz    566     Candida albicans
kkk     888     Candida albicans
```

---

If the number of species is 'too large' and requires an excessive number of `close()` calls, we can pre-sort `krakenfile`; a reduced number of `close()` calls may improve performance:

```
awk '
BEGIN        { FS="\t" }
FNR==NR      { sp = $0
               gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"_",sp)
               specie[$0]
               fname[$0] = sp "_lines.txt"
               next
             }
$3 in specie { if (prev != $3 )                   # if this is a new specie then ...
                  close(fname[prev])              # close the previous file
               prev = $3                          # save the new specie
               print $0 > fname[$3]               # print current line to associated file
             }
' fungalname <(sort -t$'\t' -k3,3 krakenfile)
```

This generates:

```
$ head *_lines.txt
==> Aspergillus_fumigatus_lines.txt <==
xxxx    548     Aspergillus fumigatus
aaaa    598     Aspergillus fumigatus

==> Candida_albicans_lines.txt <==
zzzz    566     Candida albicans
kkk     888     Candida albicans
```

**NOTES:**

- the order of the lines in the `*_lines.txt` files is based on the order of the lines as they're read from `krakenfile`
- OP can include more `-k#,#` args if the `*_lines.txt` contents need to be sorted by additional columns